# Is it possible to create pointers in C without a specific datatype

Tags: c, pointers, memory, types, low-level

So I started a programming project, and I found out it would make everything easier if I could just make a pointer without declaring it as `char*`, `int*` and so on and just specify the size somewhere else. I searched around but couldn't find anything useful.

Right now my idea would be to make everything a `char*` and just unite them with bit shifting and or operations if it isn't a string. If this is too low level for C, what language lets me do this, I prefer not to use assembly because it isn't cross platform enough.

**edit:**
So i forget to mention it should allocate memory at runtime, and to not waste too much memory i want to allocate memory depending on the size.
For example i want to allocate 1 byte for char sized values and 2 bytes for int sized values and so on. The size is predefined in a file, but is not known until the file is read which should be read in runtime rather then compiling time.

Comment: Any particular reason `void*` isn't on the menu ? You can convert it to whatever object pointer type you want, including everything you just described. I'm rather suspicious this has a strong [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) aroma unless *much* better clarification is provided [*in your question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45689027/edit).

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Why do you want to use "generic" pointers? What is the use-case? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and reflect on how your question could be one (asking for help about a solution to a for us unknown problem).

Comment: No i just didn't think about it. i didn't know it could be used as pointers. i'll just try it.

Comment: Fair warning since you mentioned it, if portability is a goal, don't do pointer arithmetic with `void*`

Comment: to the XY problem, its both for learning about the langauge and because i need it to implement my own datatypes at runtime

Comment: @CLover32 Ah. ok. Well, there is plenty of Q&A on this site about proper use of `void*` in C, the do's and don'ts, etc. There's not much to them, but if you get stuck, there's probably the info you need here if you search it out. Best of luck.

Comment: If you want to implement your own [*Abstract Data Type* (or ADT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) I rather suggest you use [*opaque data types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type) through the use of [*opaque pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) to structures. Much like `FILE` is used for the standard I/O functions.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Knowing the type of the pointed-at data is an entirely good thing. Even if you use void pointers, generic programming through void pointers should be avoided if possible. Usually there exist more elegant and type safe ways to achieve generic programming.

Comment: "i need it to implement my own datatypes at runtime" Most likely you do _not_ need to do this in any given scenario... This does indeed just sound like a solution looking for a fitting problem to solve, rather than the solution to an existing problem.

Comment: Do you want to write what i need datatypes at runtime for? it will be a wall of text and just asking politely about the problem i have. And you may misunderstand me, but i need to create a given datatype depending on other factors i don't now at compiling times.

Comment: @CLover32 we're not asking for a wall of text, but just for some lines explaining your use case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a **generic pointer type** in C for exactly this reason: `void *`.

You can convert any data pointer type implicitly to and from `void *`:

```
char foo[] = "bar";
void *ptr = foo;

// ...

char *str = ptr;
```

But be aware that you still have to know the correct type. Accessing an object through a pointer of the wrong type would be *undefined behavior*.

---

There are two things you can't do with `void *`:

- You can't do pointer arithmetics on it (this includes indexing). `void` is an *incomplete type*, so it doesn't have a known size. Some compilers allow arithmetics on `void *` by assuming the size of a `char`, but this is an extension and **not portable**.
- You can't dereference a `void *`. `void` is "nothing", so it wouldn't be meaningful.

Comment: I was just about it try it, but i heard it wouldn't be portable by doing so?

Comment: It is portable if you cast it back to the original type. You have to know what it was when it was created. Just pointer arithemtics is not defined for `void*` and so that is not portable. But you would do pointer arithmetics at a concrete pointer type.

Comment: @CLover32 Adding some clarification on that

Comment: But can i also declare it as an void* from the start? Because my problem is that i should be able to initialize an unknown size to the specific pointer. Or do i have to declare one of each pointer to initialize and free them?

Comment: @CLover32 maybe you should ask another question showing your *exact* code, I don't get what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `void* ptr = malloc(8)` would allocate 8 bytes. How you use them is up to you.

Comment: @CLover32 AndreKampling is correct here, but be aware the first write to an area returned by `malloc()` determines the *effective type* of that object, so it's better to assign the result of `malloc()` to a concrete type *right away* (like `char *str = malloc(8)`).

Comment: Okay i'l try to rewrite my question/problem, but the problem is it should be done at runtime, like i get a number and it should be allocated at a pointer with a size. But the size is unknown.

Comment: @CLover32 this smells like you want to determine types at runtime, something that's impossible in C. A compiled C program doesn't have any type information. Think about your solution and, indeed, post it as a different question.

Comment: I mean it is possible since some interpreted languages are made in C, I have a way to do it, it's just a bit clumsy since i need an array/linked list for each variable type the way i did it before.

Comment: "*I mean it is possible since some interpreted languages are made in C*" <- and these languages store variables probably in some `struct`, together with type information. So no, it's not possible in C, you have to come up with your own solution how you store type information.

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought, but i just wanted to ask here if anybody knew if the described was possible, which it seems like it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some misconception about data types, and what compile-time data types and run-time data types are. So first an example from C#, which is a programming language, where the distinction between compile-time data types and run-time data types matters. In C# you can write something like

```
IEnumerable<int> myEnumerable = new List<int>();
```

Here, the `myEnumerable` object has compile-time data type `IEnumerable<int>` and run-time data-type `List<int>`.

However, in the C programming language, there is no related concept, because C doesn't have such a strong type system. Essentially, in the C programming language, all information you store in variables is binary data that is stored somewhere in the virtual memory of the process. This data has no type information assigned to it. As a consequence, you cannot reconstruct the type of the data by simply looking at the data. In the C programming language, you can cast the data to any data type you like.

As already mentioned by other users, you can use `void` if you don't know the specific type of your data.